# Is prohibiting proxies and VPN in terms and conditions of a website legal?

Tags: terms-of-service

I found a service on an online website that prohibited the use of online anonymisers in the terms of service as stated here :

> The use of the Games and Services using anonymiser services (e.g. proxies) or other processes that conceal the location of the residence or the usual place of residence of the User is prohibited.

I'm from France and the service is available in my country.

My question is, is that legal ? And is that effective (ie should I care about that) ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to use their game, you do it with access according to their limitations. Don't like the limitations? Don't play the game. There is no reason at all to think this is/should be illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's legal. Yes it's effective.

If you sign up and then breach the terms they can do whatever the licence says they can do (terminate it probably) and whatever the law allows them to do (sue for damages, seek an injunction etc.)